# Using colon to specify a sequence in function

Tags: r

I just started r about a week ago. In my directory, I have csv files named 001, 002,...010,...331. In my partial function below, the user is requested to enter id (e.g. 1:9). The id is then converted into 001, 002, 003,...009. However, if the user enters say 1:10 for the id, the function will output id [10] as "0010" instead of as "010". This causes the rest of my function to fail. Any suggestions on what might be going on? If I enter 1:10, I want to get 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009 and **010**.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id) {

    if((id>=1) && (id<10)) {
            fn <- paste("00",id,sep="")
            print(fn)
    } else if((id>=10) && (id<=99)) {
            fn <- paste("0",id,sep="")
            print(fn)
    } else {
            fn <- id
            print(fn)
    }
```

Please I don't want to use R apply function for this. I have not gotten that far.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of time using `sprintf` - e.g. `sprintf("%03d",1:10)`

Comment: I just replaced all that with `fn <- sprintf("%03d",id)` and it worked like charm. This looks just like `System.out.printf` in Java. But any clue why my first method failed? I can't fathom it. And we've not been taught this sleek sprintf method in class which suggests my first method may still work with some tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is close but its only evaluating a single number `id`. I added a `for` loop to handle a range of numbers:

```
pollutantmean <- function(idrange) {
  for(id in idrange){
  if((id>=1) && (id<10)) {
    fn <- paste("00",id,sep="")
    print(fn)
  } else if((id>=10) && (id<=99)) {
    fn <- paste("0",id,sep="")
    print(fn)
  } else {
    fn <- id
    print(fn)
  }}
}
```

I removed the directory and pollutant arguments but they can easily be added back in. This function will evaluate all the numbers in the range of interest and print them out:

```
R> pollutantmean(1:10)
[1] "001"
[1] "002"
[1] "003"
[1] "004"
[1] "005"
[1] "006"
[1] "007"
[1] "008"
[1] "009"
[1] "010"
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

This puts leading "0"'s to a width of 3 characters with the numeric values being taken as stings.

```
sprintf("%03s", 1:10)
 [1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems is that you are using an `if` statement and the short circuiting `&&` operator. In this case `&&` will only look at the first element of the vector `id` and make a decision there. In this case `(1>=1) && (1<10)` so it executes that first block. Then you call `fn <- paste("00",id,sep="")` which is vectorized so it operates on the entire `id` vector so it adds '00' to every element. You seem to be treating the function like there is some implicit loop but there is not.

Of course @thelastemail's suggestion of `fn <- sprintf("%03d",id)` is the right one in this case, but just for the sake of discussion, your code could be re-written as

```
fn <- paste(ifelse(id<10, "00", ifelse(id<100, "0", "")),id,sep="")
```

because `ifelse` does have a kind of implied loop in that it can make different decisions for every element in the vector.

Comment: This also works. Great! Do you know how I can format to 3 decimal places without using sprintf? Sprintf outputs a string. I want an integer.

Comment: @sedeh Well, first, integers don't have decimal places. And if you're worried about formatting, then it sounds like you do want a string. Otherwise, what's the difference between 010 and 10? The value you feed into sprintf is the "numeric" value, and what you get out is the formatted "character" value.