# How do I combine multiple .csv files in R

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and have a folder containing ~300 .csv files. I am trying to merge all the data into one file so that I can carry out some basic arithmetic on it. I have tried searching the web however the function I have tried keep bringing me errors eg

```
 master <- list.files(path = "~/")
master <- do.call("rbind", lapply("001.csv" "002.csv", read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

gives back `Error: unexpected string constant in ""329.csv" "330.csv""`
etc

and the following

```
master <- do.call( rbind, lapply(`001.csv`,`002.csv` function(nam){ 
  cbind(name=nam, read.file(paste0(nam,".csv"), header=TRUE) )
}))
```

gives `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Would anyone be able to help? If so could you please explain so that someone who is new to programming will be able to follow.

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242065/trying-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-in-r), or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666073/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-files-in-r)

Comment: The first error means that you cannot use `"001.csv" "002.csv"` . Maybe try `list("001.csv", "002.csv"`) instead.

Comment: @Sotos if it's a duplicate please flag as such

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your code almost worked, you forgot to put the file names in a vector. You could make a sequence of the file names with

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(c("001.csv", "001.csv"), read.csv, header = T))
```

If the files are all in the form "001.csv" you could use the following function that automates the names of the csv files, for example if we have 001.csv until 10.csv you could use:

```
pollutantmean <- function(idrange) {
  output <- c()
  for(id in idrange){
    if((id>=1) && (id<10)) {
      output <- c(output, paste("00",id,sep=""))
    } else if((id>=10) && (id<=99)) {
      output <- c(output, paste("0",id,sep=""))
    } else {
      output <- c(output,id)
    }}
  output
}


do.call("rbind",lapply(paste0(pollutantmean(1:10),".csv"), read.csv, header = T))
```

Credits to [Using colon to specify a sequence in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623429/using-colon-to-specify-a-sequence-in-function) which I used to create the pollutantmean function.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this and it seemed to work.

```
files_full <- list.files("specdata", full.names=TRUE)

dat <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:332) {
      dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_full[i]))
    }
    str(dat)
```

Thanks for all your help